# Is php/cURL the good tool to log into this website?

Tags: php, php-curl

I am currently using cURL/php to log into several websites and retrieve data. I am still a beginner with cURL/php, but until now it worked very fine.

I used each time more or less the same code as the log pages were pretty similar.

But the last website is different. You can access [here](http://syder-rontalon.dyndns.org/prelogin).
There is a double log page, one for the id, and then after, one for the password. The first one is using a post request. So i use it to try to access to the second log page.

In the html of the page, there is a noscript tag saying : javascript must be enabled to login.
I know the question might sound stupid but is this a real issue for php/cURL ? Does it really prevent me to log in with php/cURL ?

Because it doesn't seems to manage to log with the id. Even though any words seems to work for the id.
Second issue i face : even if i would access to the second page, there is no post request in this one. So i don't know how i could log after that. It seems to use a js function to handle it.

So i simply wrote this code :

```
function logMe($id, $password, $loginUrl) {
        $cookieFilePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/SYDER-VISION/api/tmp/cookie.txt';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFilePath);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFilePath);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $postRequest = "j_username=" . $id;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postRequest);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        echo ' Content ' . $content;
        return $content;
}
```

There is no error from curl_error() and the curl_getinfo() is fine. But in the end it returns nothing and i am not logged.

I've read the other posts about php/cURL returning nothing, but none of the solutions worked for me.

So my questions are : is there a way to log into this website with cURL/php or not ? If not, what i should do ? Should i use another way to scrape ?

I deeply thank you for your answers.

Comment: If it requires JavaScript then you need a browser to make it work. No simple HTTP client can do it. You maybe need a headless browser if you want to try and automate it

Comment: Mmmh that's what i was afraid of. Thank you @ADyson. In between i've looked for those kind of browser. Seems like PhantomJs can do the job.